# Continue statement in plpgsql doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want the output to be continue, why doent it work?

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
code number(2) := 7;
begin
  if not code = 3 or not code = 7 then
     dbms_output.put_line('GO TO ERRORPAGE');
     else
     dbms_output.put_line('CONTINUE...');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: `set serveroutput on;` is an Oracle-ism. It doesn't make sense in PostgreSQL.

Comment: That is not valid PL/pgSQL and will not run in Postgres (even if you remove `set serveroutput on`). Are you sure you are using Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement will always evaluate to `true` as code can never be 3 and 7 at the same time. You probably want to change to this:

```
not(code = 3 or code = 7)
```

To elaborate further, lets look at a few examples. First let's assume `code := 7` as per your example. This case the two parts of your if statement evaluate as follows:

```
not code = 3 --> True
not code = 7 --> False
```

As at least one of your conditions has been met, the `or` statement will evaluate to true.

Secondly, let's assume `code := 3`. In this case your `if` conditions evaluate to:

```
not code = 3 --> False
not code = 7 --> True
```

And again your `or` statement evaluates to `True`.

Now looking at the final case where `code` is different than 3 or 7, let's say `code := 5`, your conditions evaluate as follows:

```
not code = 3 --> True
not code = 7 --> True
```

And in this case your `or` condition will be `True` as well.

Comment: Why? could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have elaborated my answer.